# RandomAccessFile: Setting all items to the same number of bytes?

Tags: java, bluej, randomaccessfile

```
junk.writeBytes("Henry McCollum");
junk.writeInt = 9304029494;
junk.writeBytes("Toronto");
```

If the above example were all ints, I could just set the record size to be equal to 12(since 3 ints * 4 bytes = 12), but how would I know how big the 2 string are for name and city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to record the size of the string:

```
junk.writeInt("Henry McCollum".length());
junk.writeBytes("Henry McCollum");
//and so on
```

When reading read the int and then the correct number of bytes specified by that int.

Comment: But if there are names of different sizes won't the record size be different for each one?

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt Yes, and specifying the record size lets you read them safely.